# Python Add Delimiter to Variable

Tags: python, json, http

So I have a HTTP POST from a device to my flask server, that sends the following message:

```
dump= '{"on":"false"}'
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000', data=dump,
                  headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

From the Flask server, I then try to PUT to another device on my network:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signal():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.get_json()
        print(content)
        r = requests.put("http://192.168.1.102/api/F5La7UpN6XueJZUts1QdyBBbIU8dEvaT1EZs1Ut0/lights/5/state/", content)
        return jsonify(content)
    else:
        return 'Hello, world!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The only problem is the apostrophe delimiter is removed after I send the first HTTP Request. How could I get add a delimiter around a variable?

Comment: Can you show us what is the content of your `content` variable after you `print` it?

Comment: `{"on":"false"}`

Comment: Tried this? content = "'" + content + "'"

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

`content = "'" + str(request.get_json()) "'"`

or you can also try the `str.format` way:

`content = "'{}'".format(str(request.get_json()))`

Hope it helps.

EDIT:

Converted the returned `dict` of request.get_json() to `str` before formatting.

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: Can't convert 'dict' object to str implicitly` should I try eval or something else?

Comment: You want to send `content` as a dictionary or as plain string? If plain string then you first have to convert it into a string, that I just missed in my answer, but now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to send a quoted string.

Maybe one of these helps.

```
In [1]: d = {"on":"false"}

In [2]: repr(d)
Out[2]: "{'on': 'false'}"

In [3]: import json

In [4]: s = json.dumps(d)

In [5]: str(s)
Out[5]: '{"on": "false"}'

In [6]: repr(s)
Out[6]: '\'{"on": "false"}\''
```